# How many characters are visible like a space, but are not a space characters?

Tags: php, regex

If I want to discover the hexadecimal equivalent of a space in PHP I can play with `bin2hex`:

```
php > echo var_dump(bin2hex(" "));
string(2) "20"
```

I can also obtain space character from "20"

```
php > echo var_dump(hex2bin("20"));
string(1) " "
```

But there exist Unicode versions of a "visible" space:

```
php > echo var_dump(hex2bin('c2a0'));
string(2) " "
```

So, I can get some string (for example from HTTP requests) where I cannot recognize the "no break space" with my eyes. So, ...

```
$string = preg_replace('~\x{00a0}~siu', ' ', $string);
```

Is there a better way to find and replace all "space like" characters in PHP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of a [Unicode category `\p{Zs}`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php):

> `Zs`    Space separator

```
$string = preg_replace('~\p{Zs}~u', ' ', $string);
```

The `\p{Zs}` Unicode category  class will match [these space-like symbols](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm):

```
Character   Name
U+0020      SPACE
U+00A0      NO-BREAK SPACE
U+1680      OGHAM SPACE MARK
U+2000      EN QUAD
U+2001      EM QUAD
U+2002      EN SPACE
U+2003      EM SPACE
U+2004      THREE-PER-EM SPACE
U+2005      FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
U+2006      SIX-PER-EM SPACE
U+2007      FIGURE SPACE
U+2008      PUNCTUATION SPACE
U+2009      THIN SPACE
U+200A      HAIR SPACE
U+202F      NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
U+205F      MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
U+3000      IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```

Comment: It won't even match a tab

Comment: @anubhava: I thought the question is about matching *space-like* symbols, not *tab-like* symbols.

Comment: Not sure how to define a **space-like** Should it include formfeed, Linefeed or not?

Comment: Wow, ... I've just opened a sort of Pandora's box. Thank you very much!

Comment: FYI if you *do* need to match tabs, `\s` will match all of these plus tab and vertical tab in utf-8 mode (the "u" modifier).